# save TextField input flutter

Tags: flutter

i am trying to save the data that is written in the textfield, but two strange things happen:

- the first is that if I press end from the keyboard it deletes what I typed
- second saving the data, then when I print it out a few lines of code below it gives me "nil"

what is this due in your opinion?

```
child: TextField(
                          controller: _textEditingController,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            //FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                            new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),
                          ],
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            filled: true,
                            hintText: localization.placeholder_pay,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onChanged:(p) {
                            price = p;
                          },
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
onPressed: () async {
                        //var tickets = _textEditingController.text;
                        print('WORK: ${_textEditingController.text}');
```

UPDATE

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
String price;
//String code;
Size size = MediaQuery
    .of(context)
    .size;

Size cardSize = Size(
  size.width * .9,
  size.height * .45,
);
      return Dialog(
        backgroundColor: appColors.primaryColor,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: cardSize.height,
          width: cardSize.width,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: -35,
                left: -25,
                child: Transform.rotate(
                  angle: .9,
                  child: Container(
                    color: appColors.red,
                    height: 60,
                    width: 60,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 5 + size.height * .02,
                bottom: 10 + size.height * .057,
                child: Container(
                  width: cardSize.width * .85,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: AutoSizeText(
                          localization.payment_receive,
                          maxLines: 2,
                          style: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .primaryTextTheme
                              .bodyText1
                              .copyWith(
                            color: appColors.green,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                          maxFontSize: 20,
                          minFontSize: 20,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: AutoSizeText(
                          userDataByCode.firstName + " " + userDataByCode.surname,
                          maxLines: 1,
                          style: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .primaryTextTheme
                              .bodyText1
                              .copyWith(
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                          maxFontSize: 20,
                          minFontSize: 20,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _textEditingController,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            //FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                            new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),
                          ],
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            filled: true,
                            hintText: localization.placeholder_pay,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onChanged:(p) {
                            price = p;
                          },
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: AutoSizeText(
                                "Saldo rimanente:",
                                style: Theme
                                    .of(context)
                                    .primaryTextTheme
                                    .bodyText1
                                    .copyWith(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: appColors.green,
                                ),
                                maxLines: 1,
                                group: _group,
                              ),
                            ),
                            AutoSizeText(
                                  NumberFormat.currency(
                                      locale: "it",
                                      decimalDigits: 2,
                                      symbol: "€")
                                      .format(userDataByCode.balance / 100),
                                style: Theme
                                    .of(context)
                                    .primaryTextTheme
                                    .bodyText1
                                    .copyWith(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: appColors.black,
                                ),
                                group: _group,
                              ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
                  Positioned(
                bottom: 10,
                width: size.width * .4,
                height: size.height * .05,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        child: Container(
                    height: size.height * .03,
                            child: AutoSizeText(
                      localization.btn_pay,
                      style: Theme
                          .of(context)
                          .primaryTextTheme
                          .button
                          .copyWith(fontSize: 50),
                      maxLines: 1,
                      stepGranularity: .1,
                    ),
                  ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                    var tickets = int.parse(_textEditingController.text);
                    print('WORK: ${tickets}');

                    connection.makePayment(context, num_ticket: tickets, codice: "ABC124");
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

}
}

Comment: You can add more code for your widget, please.

Comment: @FelipeVergara i Update :)

Comment: Your value is stored in price.
```print(price);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, assuming it is a subclass of type stateful widget.

You should not define your variables inside build (), because when you change state this is rendered again and you lose its value.

These must be defined above the build ().

Second, here is an example where a TextField is used and after pressing the button the value of the controller is displayed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFieldExample extends StatefulWidget {
  TextFieldExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextFieldExampleState createState() => _TextFieldExampleState();
}

class _TextFieldExampleState extends State<TextFieldExample> {
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  String price = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _textEditingController,
          inputFormatters: [
            //FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
          ],
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          onChanged: (p) {
            price = p;
          },
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        FlatButton(onPressed: () => setState(() {
          print('Price value: $price');
        }), child: Text('SAVE')),
        Text(_textEditingController.text)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```